# I would like to dynamically set DataGridCell background color or style based on colors in a database for that specific cell only. How do I do this?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a DataTable that has a person's name and color in ARGB.

I have been able to create brushes and/or styles from the color individually but have trouble binding the cellStyle of DataGridTextColumn of WindowsToolkit DataGrid in a UWP project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7C4P.png)

The Database is bound as ItemsSource to the DataGrid and shows correctly but unable to pass on the color/brush/style to cellStyle.

How do I achieve this?

```
    <Custom:DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FrozenColumnCount="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="1480" CanUserSortColumns="True" Grid.Row="1">
        <Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="ProvNum" Binding="{Binding [0]}" Tag="ProvNum" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="ProvStyle" Binding="{Binding [1]}" Tag="ProvStyle" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Provider" Binding="{Binding [2]}" Tag="Provider" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Production" Binding="{Binding [3], Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:C1}'}" Tag="Production" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Adjustments" Binding="{Binding [4], Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:C1}'}" Tag="Adjustments" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Writeoffs" Binding="{Binding [5], Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:C1}'}" Tag="Writeoffs" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Income" Binding="{Binding [6], Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:C1}'}" Tag="Income" />
            <Custom:DataGridTextColumn Header="Net Production" Binding="{Binding [7], Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:C1}'}" CellStyle="{StaticResource ProductionColumn}" Tag="NetProduction" />
        </Custom:DataGrid.Columns>
    </Custom:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using DataGrid from the community toolkit? If so, it seems no direct way for the DataGrid to do this. But you could use DataGridTemplateColumn type, it enables you to create your own column types by specifying the cell templates used to display values. Set the CellTemplate property to specify the contents of cells and you can bind background with the following Border.

```
<controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    //just one column
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
        <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Person">
                <Border Background="{x:Bind CellForColorInDataTable}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    // another colunm
    <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="ProvNum" ....../>
    ......            
</controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Yes I am using DataGrid from community toolkit. I tried this but would like to set the Background as the style or the brush. How do I do this?

Comment: Also for some reason, it keeps saying local:ProviderProductions is not a part of using:OpenReports

Comment: The type of the CellForColorInDataTable property from the example is the SolidColorBrush type.